# ASP.NET: Trying to route all requests to uri's that end in .html to a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I tried different things I found online, but nothing worked so far;

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />    
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler" />
```

and a route like;

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiHtml",
            url: "{*id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "Test", action="Index" },
            constraints: new { id = @".*\.html" }
);
```

but nothing seems to call my controller.

Everything I try just shows a 404 because it tries to load the file from disk via the static file handler.